# Error in cpp file of an arduino library

Tags: c++, libraries, hardware

I am working on a project which includes Arduino and a fingerprint scanner. It is completely based on embedded system.
But then, I have downloaded a library for the fingerprint scanner. When I run the program I get an error which maps to the cpp file of the library file. See below to see the error and the library file.

**Error**

FPS_GT511C3\FPS_GT511C3.c.cpp.o: In function `Command_Packet::GetPacketBytes()':
C:\Users\Dipti\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FPS_GT511C3/FPS_GT511C3.c.cpp:17: undefined reference to`operator new[](unsigned int)'
FPS_GT511C3\FPS_GT511C3.c.cpp.o: In function `FPS_GT511C3::GetResponse()':
C:\Users\Dipti\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FPS_GT511C3/FPS_GT511C3.c.cpp:735: undefined reference to`operator new[](unsigned int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**Library File (CPP)**

> byte* packetbytes= new byte[12];
>
> byte* resp = new byte[12];

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how you're building the code, or even what compiler you are using, which makes it very hard to answer.

I guess you are failing to link to the C++ runtime. If you're using GCC then you should be using `g++` not `gcc` to build C++ code, so that the C++ runtime library is used automatically.

Comment: Okay. I am using gcc compiler here. How can i get a g++ compiler. I dont know much of c++ programming. Please help me to get a g++ compiler or tell me where it is available. I am using Dev cpp here.